# How to copy a file with wildcards in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch, script

I want to COPY and REPLACE files from one folder to another, but I cant seem to get it to work

```
copy D:\FolderPath\Pictures\test.txt C:\Users\FolderPath\Desktop\test\test*.txt
pause
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

For your immediate concern, you want to move that wildcard to your source, not your destination, and just list the target directory as your destination. Also, tack a "/Y" option on the end to automatically overwrite files in the destination. So something like this should work:

```
copy D:\FolderPath\Pictures\test*.txt C:\Users\FolderPath\Desktop\test /Y
```

***If you are copying entire directories***, then you might want to step up to ROBOCOPY  as it has a great many options that can handle most any situation you can imagine, including overwriting, not overwriting, not adding new files, and purging old files when new ones are absent. You can [read more about it here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

Comment: Hey Thanks for the quick replay it helps!! But the issue that I am running into is within the source folder there is test1.txt and I want it to copy to text.txt in the destination. Does that make sense, is there anything I need to change. In addition the command runs but there is now a test1.txt and a test.txt in the destination folder.

Comment: @AlexKurtz you will likely need to rename each file individually (as given in the other answer to this question). If you need to do this in a pattern of some kind, than neither of these answers (by themselves) are likely what you want. You'll probably want to check out a more advance language than batch, such as [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Answer (score 1):

To copy while changing the name from `test1.txt` to `test.txt`, do:

```
copy D:\FolderPath\Pictures\test1.txt C:\Users\FolderPath\Desktop\test\test.txt
```